# Cant upload a signed APK to PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play, apk, publish, signed

I made an app and I published it on the PlayStore.
I made an update and now I'm trying to re-import it into the Android publish web site.

I generated my app like this : (with Android Studio)

- Build
- Generate Signed APK...
- I choosed my app
- Click "next"
- And I used the same key, same password etc ...

The apk is succefully generated (and signed).
[image]

But when I tried to upload the app on the publish website (to update the app online) it tells me:

> You have imported an APK file without a signature. You must create an APK file with a signature.

[image]

Have you got an idea why it's crashing?

It's contradincting, Android studio tells me that the signed app is generated but the website tells me it's not a signed app.

**EDIT :**
I tryed to "Build -> Clean Project" and "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart..." without success. I also tryed to make a new project, copy past all code and retry :/

Comment: Can you translate the language in image in english ?

Comment: I put it just above the image : "You have imported an APK file without a signature. You must create an APK file with a signature".

Comment: What it's trying to say is to sign all the apks be digitally signed with a certificate. Refer to this link https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: @TomSkat read above link

Comment: Thanks for your help, I already have a look at this link, But yes, I signed my APK like the older versions :/ I also tryed to put my key path and password in "Open Module Settings" but no results.

Comment: Are you sure you picked the correct APK for upload?

Comment: Yap x) It's from my Desktop and I have only one APK on it xD

Comment: This shouldn't happen try cleaning your project and run the entire process once again.

Comment: Can you say me how to clean my project please ?

Comment: Build + Clean project in android studio

Comment: It's the same result, Android Studio say me that the signed APK is succefully generated but AndroidPublish website say me it's not a signed APK...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you're creating your keystore correctly and none of the solutions in AMAN SINGH's answer worked for you.

There's a new signing scheme in Android called Apk Signing Scheme v2. 
https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2

When you're signing your apk there're two checkboxes. 
v1 (jar signing)
v2 (apk signing)

v1 signature is required, if the APK's `minSdkVersion` is **23** and lower. Android versions before `Android Nougat` (`API Level 24`) **ignore** v2 signatures so apks which don't have a valid v1 signature will be **rejected** by Play Store.

> In Android 7.0, APKs can be verified according to the APK Signature
>   Scheme v2 (v2 scheme) or JAR signing (v1 scheme). Older platforms
>   ignore v2 signatures and only verify v1 signatures.

[image]

**Edit:**

Thanks `Alex Klyubin` for information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was thinking I tryed that without results but It's working :P THANKS A LOT :D

Comment: v1 signature is required if the APK's minSdkVersion is 23 and lower -- Android versions before Android Nougat (API Level 24) ignore v2 signatures and will thus reject APKs which don't have a valid v1 signature. On top of that, Google Play currently requires that all APKs, regardless of their minSdkVersion, have a valid v1 signature.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the language in which the image is there but if you already uploaded your `APK` once then,

*) You need to use same signed keystore signature which you used first time at generating signed APK.

*) Check your Manifest.xml, `android:debuggable="true"` if this is there remove this line or make `debuggable="false"`

*) check `versionCode' should be greater than last uploaded

*) Check `versionName` should be greater than last uploaded

*) Tick Mark in both the column while building the Signed APK

Comment: Thanks for your help @AMAN SINGH. I haven't got lines like "android:debuggable" in my manifest, I used the same signature (stored it in a server to don't loose it). and my versionCode and my versionName are greater than the other one, It's my fourth update and I never had problems :/

Comment: And it's french, look at the translation above (in yellow :P)

Comment: pls recheck once more and generate signed `APK`

Comment: because as it's saying its not signed so please do is once more

Comment: I rechecked now, No problem, need you a Skype conf to show you I did what I can ? :P It seems like you think I did a bad thing :P

Comment: hey no I didn't said like that. As you already mentioned everything in ques itself. anyway try to 'Invalidate caches/ Restart` and rebuild it again. if not work will see any other options

Comment: It's the same result, Android Studio say me that the signed APK is succefully generated but AndroidPublish website say me it's not a signed APK...